# How can i use `parse = T` and functions like round in a geom_text paste command?

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I want to add the results of multiple linear models to my plot as a `geom_text` , they are stored in the same `tibble` as the scatterplot data. Since i want to use the approx symbol (`%~~%`) and the r squared as superscript (`r^2`) is set `parse=T` inside the geom_text command. However, it gives me:

```
Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:14: unexpected symbol
1: r^2 %~~%0.25 RMSE
```

with an arrow pointing to the `M` in `RMSE`. If i omit the `parse=T`, it will plot, but without the formatting. Further if i run it in `Rstudio` by simply clicking in the plot command structure and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> it gives me:

```
Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?
```

If i i mark the code part and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> i gives throws the unexpected symbold error.
Does anybody know why and how to circumvent this? I already tried leaving out the `RMSE` string part, then it simply throws the error on another location of the string. It seems to be connected to the `round` command but i do not now how to circumvent this.
Here is the whole plot command:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value_height, y = rpm, col = variant )) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', col = 'black', se = F) +
  # geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = F) +
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(
      'r^2 %~~%', round(R2_height, 2), ' RMSE %~~% ', round(RMSE_height, 2),
      '\n y =', round(intercept_height, 2),'+', round(slope_height, 2 ), 'x')),size = 4, x = 0.3, y = 10, col = 'black', parse = T) +
  facet_wrap(~date_rpm) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.8,.2), legend.direction = 'horizontal') +
  scale_color_discrete(name='') +
  ylab('Rising Plate Meter (RPM)') +
  xlab('Crop Surface Height (CSH) [cm]') + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3))
```

This is how it look with an formated string, but i want the equal signs to be approx signs and the r2 to be in superscript.
[image: Unformatted Text Plot]

data:

```
    df <- structure(list(date_rpm = structure(c(18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 18416, 
18416, 18416, 18416, 18416), class = "Date"), rpm = c(5, 3.5, 
3, 6, 9, 5, 3, 3, 4, 13, 21, 10, 7.5, 12, 16, 12, 13, 9, 18, 
10, 7, 11, 12, 7, 11, 15, 11, 14, 14, 16, 13, 10, 10, 10, 16, 
5, 8, 8, 10, 7, 9, 8, 4.5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4.5, 20, 5.5, 5, 
7, 9, 5, 8.5, 10, 17, 4, 8, 15, 7, 14, 12, 15, 9, 22, 13, 9, 
16, 6, 9, 13, 12, 19.5, 16, 7, 13, 9.5, 5, 12, 19, 11, 7, 6, 
19, 12, 15), plotname = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", 
"B3", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C3", 
"C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C3", "C2", "C2", "C2", 
"C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", 
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "C2"), variant = c("Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", 
"Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", 
"Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Moderate", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", 
"Very Lenient", "Very Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", 
"Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", 
"Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", 
"Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient", "Lenient"), diff = structure(c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), class = "difftime", units = "days"), value_height = c(0.0747471996861645, 
0.0519722114175053, 0.0444986718332666, 0.0338748996540651, 0.130905933869191, 
0.0627344897669605, 0.0461518377320379, 0.0496649014747749, 0.0346351036658654, 
0.197689089000735, 0.228481029642039, 0.0869697505592281, 0.247327755659054, 
0.110378037151108, 0.190863379116716, 0.153554587528623, 0.214562251650054, 
0.173082661424947, 0.309699486041891, 0.117518367930355, 0.0411031690694518, 
0.167414698107489, 0.367566883054554, 0.0802824884398371, 0.157873638605667, 
0.189377089678231, 0.125737899389022, 0.158878721039871, 0.241583593960466, 
0.238216268605199, 0.352655443094544, 0.121164650752627, 0.119100065312834, 
0.087414577089507, 0.279764767350822, 0.116740391172212, 0.146888537284655, 
0.0964947561932425, 0.116610769498146, 0.0829571222854873, 0.0387162030753443, 
0.0489122439653445, 0.0316104231209591, 0.0265153787903867, 0.0384905540336997, 
0.0679986415765224, 0.0321631997318591, 0.0634453928368723, 0.0192758592508607, 
0.029608364762931, 0.0513664771770609, 0.0391104934561966, 0.040441841914736, 
0.0412192509092134, 0.0682212633964343, 0.0464335384531918, 0.0814433919972387, 
0.0871005588107639, 0.192856747879941, 0.060900984139278, 0.161748380742521, 
0.200371047197762, 0.150143034561821, 0.176932236243939, 0.126676901792869, 
0.270053961338141, 0.161895491119124, 0.125705210367839, 0.114015497713007, 
0.128272423377404, 0.120223209775727, 0.0805775270623676, 0.0944333850827992, 
0.196956766062769, 0.339835594440329, 0.203907762837206, 0.2025146484375, 
0.0979132816709321, 0.095847887870593, 0.073602084455819, 0.0895857851729434, 
0.0644812542459239, 0.320930093021716, 0.127427725956358, 0.235913659772302, 
0.108491541975636, 0.138192386950477, 0.199337716829979, 0.275268289317255
), R2_height = c(0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941, 
0.645737397976941, 0.645737397976941), slope_height = c(value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276, 
value_height = 36.3572830718276, value_height = 36.3572830718276
), intercept_height = c(5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852, 
5.28102549943852, 5.28102549943852), RMSE_height = c(3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 
3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771, 3.58862854318771
)), row.names = c(NA, -89L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a data.frame that just has the vlaues for the label, otherwise you are drawing the label over and over again on top of itself for each point in your data set. So you can create

```
labeldata <- df %>% 
   distinct(date_rpm, RMSE_height, R2_height, intercept_height, slope_height)
```

And then when you make the label, you need to create text that's a valid R plotmath expression. You can't just freely mix text and math symbols. You can see what it's currently producing with

```
with(df, paste0(
     'r^2 %~~%', round(R2_height, 2), ' RMSE %~~% ', round(RMSE_height, 2),
     '\n y =', round(intercept_height, 2),'+', round(slope_height, 2 ), 'x'))
#  [1] "r^2 %~~%0.65 RMSE %~~% 3.59\n y =5.28+36.36x"
#  [2] "r^2 %~~%0.65 RMSE %~~% 3.59\n y =5.28+36.36x"
#  [3] "r^2 %~~%0.65 RMSE %~~% 3.59\n y =5.28+36.36x"
#  ....  (many more lines repeated)
```

So you can see how many times it's trying to print that same text. And those aren't valud expressions. You can't just have multiple statements in an R expresion with just a space inbetween them, here's an alternate version using the reduced data.frame

```
with(labeldata, paste0(
     'atop(r^2 %~~%', round(R2_height, 2), '~RMSE %~~% ', round(RMSE_height, 2),
     ', y =', round(intercept_height, 2),'+', round(slope_height, 2 ), '*x)'))
# [1] "atop(r^2 %~~%0.65~RMSE %~~% 3.59, y =5.28+36.36*x)"
```

Now we only get one label and it's syntactically correct. You can use that in the `geom_text` like

```
geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(
      'atop(r^2 %~~%', round(R2_height, 2), '~RMSE %~~% ', round(RMSE_height, 2),
      ', y =', round(intercept_height, 2),'+', round(slope_height, 2 ), '*x)')),size = 4, x = 0.3, y = 10, col = 'black', 
    data=labeldata, parse = T)
```

[image]